# Remove background map Leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using Leaflet to make a cloropleth map over Europe. I would like to remove the map so that just the cloropleth layer is visible (background white).

I've tried to use different versions of map.removeLayer but I haven't been able to make a change without removing all layers.

I've also tried to alter .leaflet-container in the css.

Any ideas on how to remove the background map and keep the colored layer over the countries?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="europe_countries.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var map = L.map('map').setView([50.888571, 10.413779], 3);



    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.light'
    }).addTo(map);


    // control that shows state info on hover
    var info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
            : 'Hover over a state');
    };

    info.addTo(map);


    // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
        return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
                d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
                d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
                d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
                d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                            '#FFEDA0';
    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density)
        };
    }

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 2,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }

        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    var geojson;

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature
        });
    }

    geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);

    map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Population data &copy; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
            labels = [],
            from, to;

        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            from = grades[i];
            to = grades[i + 1];

            labels.push(
                '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
        }

        div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
        return div;
    };

    legend.addTo(map);

  function drawMap(tile){
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    });
    map.addLayer(tile);
}

</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
        }


    </style>

    <style>#map { width: 800px; height: 500px;}
.info { padding: 6px 8px; font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: white; background: white; box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-radius: 5px; } .info h4 { margin: 0 0 5px; color: #777; }
.legend { text-align: left; line-height: 18px; color: #555; } .legend i { width: 18px; height: 18px; float: left; margin-right: 8px; opacity: 0.7; }

</style>
```

Comment: Can you make a https://jsfiddle.net of this please?

Comment: Have you tried this? `map.removeLayer(map._layers[index]);`

Comment: @Alex I wasn't able to make it work in a fiddle (due to a local file, couldn't make it work in the fiddle hosted online). But it's basically this map just for Europe instead: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html

Here's a link to the Europe.js I'm using: http://europe2js-site.orionhub.org:8000/europe2.js

Comment: @ssten Thanks, but that removed the cloropleth layer and not the actual map under it, which is the problem I've been having with other solutions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm understanding the question correct, Using the example you added in the comments, I believe you can `hide` `.leaflet-tile-container`?

```
.leaflet-tile-container {
    display: none;
}
```